# extract a value attribute with web scraping in python

Tags: python, html, web

i want extract the content of a value attribute, but i have an error in my code
this is a parto of my code:

```
    link_capitolo_scelto = link_chapter_array[scelta_capitolo]
    chapter_url = simple_url + link_capitolo_scelto




    r3 = requests.get(chapter_url)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(r3.content, 'html.parser')



    lista_pagine = soup3.find(class_='top-title')

    link_pagine_array = []
    for element in lista_pagine:
        pageSelect = lista_pagine.find(id='pageSelect')
        link_pagine_array.append(pageSelect)

    # print(link_pagine_array)
    for element in link_pagine_array:
        element = element.get('value')
        print(element)
```

and this is my output:
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
the html tag is:

8
how can i solve it?

Comment: Please share the URL, complete code and  what do you want to scrape from it and problem you are facing.

Comment: the url is https://beta.mangaeden.com/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/1/  and the tag is: <option value="/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/8/" data-page="8" class="ui-state-default">8</option> i want extract the url in the value attribute

Comment: Please add those details to the question and not as comments. Thanks!

Comment: Have you gone through the basics of ```beautifulsoup``` before writing this code. I suggest you to read about it. Also mention exactly what do you want to scrape from that site ? Is it the url inside ```<option>``` tag ?

Comment: i read a cours about beautifulSoup. yes, i want scrape the url inside option tag, the course is: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=it&u=https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-python-using-beautiful-soup/

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to go through `beautifulsoup` [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and learn more about it.

Try this.

**Select the `option` tag with the attribute `data-page=8` and extract it's value.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://beta.mangaeden.com/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/1/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
p = soup.find('option', attrs = {'data-page': 8})['value']

print(p)
```

```
/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/8/
```